# send a CSV object from Javascript to C#

Tags: c#, javascript, csv

i have been searching a way to send a CSV object from Javascript to C# but all i have found is the opposite.

```
$("#send").click(function () {
        var json = $.parseJSON($("#json").val());
        var csv = JSON2CSV(json);
    });
```

the previous code is my javascript. i need to send the variable csv to my code behind in C#.
thanks in advance

Comment: I would probably stringify the CSV object (if it is a JavaScript object) and then send via the POST method via AJAX

Comment: I think you want to use some AJAX here?

Comment: @marksyzm i have the stringifyed json already in the variable json that i am passing to JSON2CSV. if so, how can i post it from here and get it from my code behind? any idea?